# Splinter WebDriverException: newSession Firefox 63.0

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, anaconda, geckodriver, splinter

I have been using Splnter with GeckoDriver and Firefox for months and all was well until Firefox upgraded to 63.0 today.

Now, when I try to run Splinter with the code below, I get immediately the error that follows it.

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser()

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-a8fa3d213da9>", line 16, in <module>
    browser = Browser()

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\splinter\browser.py", line 63, in Browser
    return driver(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\splinter\driver\webdriver\firefox.py", line 57, in __init__
    timeout=timeout, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 151, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 240, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

WebDriverException: newSession
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had to get the latest version of GeckoDriver and install it where Python.exe is kept.
Problem solved.